# Spring batch - One reader, multiple processors and writers based on field value

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a mongodb collection where all my events are saved. I want to read every event and process them according to a property field and after saved them to an another mongodb collection.

Example:

I have an event of type A, I process it and create an object A which is saved in the A mongodb collection.
Next, I have an event of type B, I process it and create an object B which is saved in the B mongodb collection.

It seems to be 1 reader, 1 processor which do the logic and N writers or 1 reader, N processors with N writers and with an unknown adapter between the reader and processors to do the routing.

The batch must see if there is new events and process them.

How can I do that?

Comment: 1 reader, N processors/writers routed with a classfier. That's enough

Comment: I must use a ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor and a ClassifierCompositeItemWriter or can I use only 1 classifierCompositeItemProcessor and then link a writer to each processor?

Comment: You'll need to use one of each.

Comment: Do you have a sample to point me?